# Controlling React component props from DOM

Tags: javascript, web, reactjs

I have a React modal I created which has two props: `isOpened` and `onClose`. This works fine from within React, however my whole site isn't completely React yet and so I want to be able to control my modal from outside of the React environment.

I have set `isOpened` to a window variable, and `onClose` to a window function that updates this variable, and this works fine on first load, but of course when these variables are updated my modal component is not re-rendered.

Is there a way to call `forceUpdate` from the DOM when I update my variable? Or am I going about this in completely the wrong way?

FYI: I am happy for a hacky solution as this is temporary until I can finish moving my site to React.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The only way to trigger a React render-cycle is to update the state of a component (or to call the root "ReactDOM.render()").

In your case, I think you could add a local state in a parent component of your Modal component, to be able to update this state from "outside" (here I used a global eventEmitter instance):

```
var ParentComponent = React.createClass({
    getInitialState: function() {
        return {isOpen: this.props.isOpen || false};
    },

    componentDidMount: function() {
        window.eventEmitter.addListener('openModal', this.onOpenModal);
        window.eventEmitter.addListener('closeModal', this.onCloseModal);
    },

    componentWillReceiveProps: function(nextProps) {
        this.setState({isOpen: nextProps.isOpen});
    },

    componentWillUnmount: function() {
        window.eventEmitter.removeListener('openModal', this.onOpenModal);
        window.eventEmitter.removeListener('closeModal', this.onCloseModal);
    },

    onOpenModal: function() {
        this.setState({isOpen: true});
    },

    onCloseModal: function() {
        this.setState({isOpen: false});
    },

    render: function() {
        return (
            <Modal isOpen={this.state.isOpen} />
        );
    },
});
```

Please note that local state is needed here only because you want it updated "from the outside". This state is also updated from the prop "isOpen" in order to work properly inside the React part of your app. But in a "React-only" app, the "isOpen" prop would be enough (no local state needed).

Comment: @Damien is there something you don't clearly understand in my proposed solution? I'm here to help.